# Get file name of image before upload - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form to upload image with:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <input id="file_input" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0" name="image[photo_new]" accept="image/*">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="title">
      <label for="image_title">Title</label>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="title" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="image[title]" maxlength="200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want when users click to `#input_file` area to choose image, then the after choosing file, the file name will display immediately in `#title` field. For example `name.png` should be `name`. I want to use JQuery to do this function but don't know how, any advises? Thank in advance.

Comment: Please show us the mark up/HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `this.value` to get the file value in a change event handler and then extract the name like

```js
$('#file_input').change(function() {
  //$('#title').val(this.value ? this.value.match(/([\w-_]+)(?=\.)/)[0] : '');
  $('#title').val(this.files && this.files.length ? this.files[0].name.split('.')[0] : '');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file_input" type="file" />
<input id="title" />
```

Comment: If I upload a file named `employees_db-full-1.0.6.tar.bz2`, the value you print displays `employees_db-full-1` truncating some of the actual file name before the extension(s)

Answer (score 2):

You can attach an event after the user chooses an image like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image').on('change', function(event) {
        // and you can get the name of the image like this:
        console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
    });
});
```

If the html is like this:

```
<input type="file" id="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have name, size and type details of selected file using below code. have a look.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#file').change(function(){
 var file = this.files[0];
 name = file.name;
 size = file.size;
 type = file.type;
 //your validation
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample code to show file name :

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<button  id="btn">Submit</button>
<div id="fname"></div>

 $(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click',function(){
    var name = $('#file').val().split('\\').pop();
    name=name.split('.')[0];
    $('#fname').html(name);
  });
})();
```

Here is [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/3qzg2vp7/1/) on jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks bro... Happy to help